# Regular Expression for URL in C Sharp for Performance Testing

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, webtest

Im using Visual Studio 2012 - Web Performance Testing tool.

In here i have an Referer URL Like this. (This is about 30 lines long, but i have kept it short)

https://first URL/Second/Third/Fourth/five/SearchResults?json=%7B%22SalesInventoryID%22%3Anull%2C%22BundleInventoryID%22%3Anull%2C%22InventorySalesPriceID%22%3Anull%2C%22SiteType%22%3A8%2C%22SiteName%22%3A%22Desert%20Club%22%2C%22PointsMin%22%3A1%2C%22PointsMax%22%3A999999%2C%22RoomType%22%3Anull%2C%22PriceMin%22%3A1%2C%22PriceMax%22%3A999999%2C%22SeasonType%22%3Anull%2C%22FrequencyType%22%3Anull%2C%22CheckInType%22%3Anull%2C%22WeekMin%22%3A1%2C%22WeekMax%22%3A52%2C%22RoomMin%22%3A%221%22%2C%22RoomMax%22%3A%22999999%22%2C%22TourID%22%3A2022154%2C%22TourLocationID%22%3A54%2C%22ListResults%22%3Anull%2C%22BundledResults%22%3Anull%2C%22TourParticipantInfo%22%3A%7B%22TourID%22%3A2022154%2C%22SiteID%22%3A1%2C%22SiteName%22%3Anull%2C%22PersonID%22%3A364182%2C%22FirstName%22%3A%22Lynn%20A.%22%2C%22LastName%22%3A%22McDougald%22%2C%22City%22%3A%22Charlotte%22%2C%22State%22%3A%22-%22%2C%22ShortState%22%3A%22-%22%2C%22Country%22%3Anull%2C%22CountryID%22%3A840%2C%22OwnerNumber%22%3A%226017104%22%2C%22OwnerStatus%22%3Anull%2C

After Search Results , everything keeps changing .

Can someone please tell me , ho do i do it if i need anything after "/fourth"

like i just need it like this - https://first URL/Second/Third/Fourth/

I tried:

```
https://first URL/Second/Third/Fourth/.*
```

and

```
https://first URL/Second/Third/Fourth/(.*)
```

it did not work .

Comment: Your regex work fine, you just need to escape each `/` (writting `\/` instead)

Comment: If you don't want the first part, place it in a lookbehind, like this : `(?<=https:\/\/first URL\/Second\/Third\/Fourth\/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the regex of @degant

`https:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/(.*)`

Capture group for everything beyond the fourth section. And dynamic content for the preceding sections, to make it take "everything after the 4th section" instead of using explicit content for each.

https://regex101.com/r/km53lt/3

Answer (score 0):

To get everything after the fourth URL, use the below

```
https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\/){4}(.*)
```

And then use capturing group 1 to get all text after the fourth `/`.

You can test it out here: [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/km53lt/5/)

**EDIT:** Suggestions from @Doqnach

Comment: `https:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/(.*)`

to make it slightly more dynamic in case the path sections can also change content.

https://regex101.com/r/km53lt/3

Comment: Thanks, good point! I was assuming OP wanted to match the base URL

Comment: If performance is important, repeating `[^\/]+\/` is a tiny bit faster than using the `(?:...){4}`. The difference is incredibly tiny though, so probably won't actually affect you much (20 vs 25 steps).